# Converting an Array of Strings into key/values Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, key, key-value

How to convert an array of multiple strings with following structure into key-value structure with php?

```
$mystring = 'first_group, second_group, third_group';
```

need to be an array like following:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [key] => first_group 
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [key] => second_group 
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [key] => third_group 
    )
)
```

Comment: Explode and process further.

Comment: `$foo = array_map(function($i) { return ['key' => $i]; }, explode(', ', 'first_group, second_group, third_group'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do this way with simple `explode()` and `foreach()`,

```
<?php
$mystring = 'first_group, second_group, third_group';
$results = explode(', ', $mystring);
foreach($results as $row){
    $expected[] = ['key'=>$row];
}
print_r($expected);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FgndX

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_map(
    function($v) { return ['key' => trim($v)]; }, 
    explode(',', 'first_group, second_group, third_group')
);
print_r($result);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/JNCeo)